# ValueError: Unsupported 'device_type'

Tags: python-3.x, netmiko

I am new to Python.
I have this code in Python:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
`sshCli = ConnectHandler(
        device_type='Cisco_ios',
        host='192.168.56.101',
        port=22,
        username='cisco',
        password='cisco123!'
        )
output = sshCli.send_command("show ip int brief")
print("show ip int brief:\n{}\n".format(output))
```

I get the following error:

```
========== RESTART: C:/Users/edanpc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lab2.2.py =========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/edanpc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lab2.2.py", line 2, in <module>
    sshCli = ConnectHandler(
  File "C:\Users\edanpc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 297, in ConnectHandler
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unsupported 'device_type' currently supported platforms are: 
a10
accedian
adtran_os
alcatel_aos
alcatel_sros
apresia_aeos
arista_eos
aruba_os
avaya_ers
avaya_vsp
broadcom_icos
brocade_fastiron
brocade_netiron
brocade_nos
brocade_vdx
brocade_vyos
calix_b6
centec_os
checkpoint_gaia
ciena_saos
cisco_asa
cisco_ios
cisco_nxos
cisco_s300
cisco_tp
cisco_wlc
cisco_xe
cisco_xr
cloudgenix_ion
coriant
dell_dnos9
dell_force10
dell_isilon
dell_os10
dell_os6
dell_os9
dell_powerconnect
dlink_ds
eltex
eltex_esr
endace
enterasys
extreme
extreme_ers
extreme_exos
extreme_netiron
extreme_nos
extreme_slx
extreme_vdx
extreme_vsp
extreme_wing
f5_linux
f5_ltm
f5_tmsh
flexvnf
fortinet
generic
generic_termserver
hp_comware
hp_procurve
huawei
huawei_olt
huawei_smartax
huawei_vrpv8
ipinfusion_ocnos
juniper
juniper_junos
juniper_screenos
keymile
keymile_nos
linux
mellanox
mellanox_mlnxos
mikrotik_routeros
mikrotik_switchos
mrv_lx
mrv_optiswitch
netapp_cdot
netgear_prosafe
netscaler
nokia_sros
oneaccess_oneos
ovs_linux
paloalto_panos
pluribus
quanta_mesh
rad_etx
raisecom_roap
ruckus_fastiron
ruijie_os
sixwind_os
sophos_sfos
ubiquiti_edge
ubiquiti_edgeswitch
ubiquiti_unifiswitch
vyatta_vyos
vyos
watchguard_fireware
yamaha
zte_zxros
>>>
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is specific to `netmiko`. The error text says the list of supported `device_type` values. To solve the error, fix the below in your code.

`device_type='cisco_ios'`

The device type should contain small `cisco_ios` instead of `Cisco_ios`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working. I can't believe this stupid mistake.

Comment: Alright :) If it's working, accept the answer. Then others won't try fixing this. Cheers!

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers